# Wrong population after document.save() in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to create a blog and return the populated blog in  the following schemas :

```
const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type:String
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        ref: 'UserTable',
        required: true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('BlogPostTable', blogSchema);
```

And

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
    },
    blogPosts: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
            ref: 'BlogPostTable'
        }
    ]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserTable', userSchema);
```

I am saving a blog like this:

```
blogRouter.post('/', async (request, response, next) => {

    const token = request.token;

    try {
        const foundUser = await userTable.findById(decodedToken.id); // Find User

        const newBlog = new blogTable({                              // Create document 
            title: request.body.title,
            text: request.body.text,
            likes: 0,
            author: foundUser._id
        });

        await newBlog.save();  // Save Blog 
        foundUser.blogPosts = foundUser.blogPosts.concat(newBlog); // update Users blogs 
        await foundUser.save(); 
        response.status(200).json(newBlog.populate('author').toJSON()); // WRONG OUTPUT 
    }
```

**However**, 
**The Author is populated wrong. There is no `username` and the `id` is an array!**

**Where did I go wrong and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below line of code to see what happens in your code:

`mongoose.set('debug', true);`

First statement: `await newBlog.save();` triggers an `insertOne` operation with a document having `author` set: `author: ObjectId("...")`

then you run `await foundUser.save();` which explicitly sets an array of blogposts:

`{ '$set': { blogPosts: [ ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...) ] }`

That makes sense becuase you used `concat` in JS code. The thing is that there's no other third query because you're trying to run `populate` on existing in-memory object which won't work - populate requires a query instead of in-memory object.

So you have to query your database again to get `author` populated:

```
let userPosts = await blogTable
        .find({ author: foundUser._id })
        .populate('author');

console.log(userPosts);
```

which triggers two queries:

```
Mongoose: blogposttables.find({ author: ObjectId("...") }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usertables.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("...") ] } }, { projection: {} })
```